# PHP - Login/Logout/expire with Session,cookie or database

Tags: php, session, cookies, authentication

Im trying to create a user class in php connected with database
Here is my class i written so far!

```
class db {
    private function conn(){
        set_exception_handler(create_function('$e','db::db_error($e);'));
        return new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb','admin','pass');  //Persistent connection without closing conn: ....$user, $pass, array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT=>true));
    }
    public static function db_error($log){
        $mylog=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']." - ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']." - ".date("d/m/Y h:i:s")." - ".$log;
        $showlog=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']." - Internal Server Error!";
        // $mylog > error information log on db or file!
        exit($showlog);
    }
    public function dbconstruction(){
        $pdo=$this->conn();
        $pdo->query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
                `uid` text NOT NULL,
                `sid` text NOT NULL,
                `did` text NOT NULL,
                `username` text NOT NULL,
                `password` text NOT NULL,
                `fullname` text NOT NULL,
                `email` text NOT NULL,
                `birthday` text NOT NULL,
                `expire` text NOT NULL
            ) DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;");
        $pdo->query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `unverified` (
                `uid` text NOT NULL,
                `token` text NOT NULL,
                `expire` text NOT NULL
            ) DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;");
        $pdo->query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sessions` (
                `uid` text NOT NULL,
                `session` text NOT NULL,
                `expire` text NOT NULL
            ) DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;");
        $pdo=null;
        return true;
    }
    public function send($a,$t){ // usage:  $db->send(array('username'=>'boss'),'users');
        if(empty($a)||count($a)<1){return false;}
        $keys=array_keys($a);
        $keys2=array_keys($a);
        foreach($keys2 as &$k){$k=':'.$k;} // ":key"
        $params=array_combine($keys2,array_values($a));
        $st=$this->conn()->prepare("INSERT INTO `$t`(".(count($keys)>1?implode(",",$keys):$keys[0]).") VALUES (".(count($keys2)>1?implode(",",$keys2):$keys2[0]).")");
        $st->execute($params);
        if($st){$st=null;return true;}
        $st=null;
        return false;
    }
    public function receive($a,$t){ // usage:  $db->receive(array('username'=>'boss'),'users');
        if(empty($a)||count($a)<1){return false;}
        $keys=array_keys($a);
        $keys2=array_keys($a);
        foreach($keys as &$k){$k=$k.' = :'.$k;} // "key = :key"
        foreach($keys2 as &$k){$k=':'.$k;} // ":key"
        $params=array_combine($keys2,array_values($a));
        $st=$this->conn()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $t WHERE ".(count($keys)>1?implode(" AND ",$keys):$keys[0]));
        $st->execute($params);
        $result=$st->fetchAll();
        $st=null;
        return $result;
    }
    public function remove($a,$t){ // usage:  $db->remove(array('token'=>'boss'),'unverified');
        if(empty($a)||count($a)<1){return false;}
        $keys=array_keys($a);
        $keys2=array_keys($a);
        foreach($keys as &$k){$k=$k.' = :'.$k;} // "key = :key"
        foreach($keys2 as &$k){$k=':'.$k;} // ":key"
        $params=array_combine($keys2,array_values($a));
        $st=$this->conn()->prepare("DELETE FROM $t WHERE ".(count($keys)>1?implode(" AND ",$keys):$keys[0]));//DELETE FROM `unverified` WHERE token = 'asd'
        $st->execute($params);
        $c=$st->rowCount();
        if($c>0){$st=null;return true;}
        $st=null;
        return false;
    }
    public function update($a,$b,$t){ // usage:  $db->update(array('password'=>'boss'),array('uid'=>$uid),'users'); // update password where uid=$uid
        if(empty($a)||count($a)<1||empty($b)||count($b)<1){return false;}
        $a_keys=array_keys($a);
        foreach($a_keys as &$k){$k=$k.'=?';} // "key=?"
        $set_params=array_values($a);       
        $b_keys=array_keys($b);
        foreach($b_keys as &$k){$k=$k.'=?';} // "key=?"
        $where_params=array_values($b);
        $params=array_merge($set_params,$where_params);
        $set=(count($a_keys)>1?implode(", ",$a_keys):$a_keys[0]);
        $where=(count($b_keys)>1?implode(" AND ",$b_keys):$b_keys[0]);
        $st=$this->conn()->prepare("UPDATE $t SET $set WHERE $where");
        $st->execute($params);
        $c=$st->rowCount();
        if($c>0){$st=null;return true;}
        $st=null;
        return false;
    }
    public function check($a,$t){ // usage:  $db->check(array('username'=>'boss'),'users');
        if(empty($a)||empty($t)||count($a)<1){return false;}
        $keys=array_keys($a);
        $keys2=array_keys($a);
        foreach($keys as &$k){$k=$k.' = :'.$k;} // "key = :key"
        foreach($keys2 as &$k){$k=':'.$k;} // ":key"
        $params=array_combine($keys2,array_values($a));
        $st=$this->conn()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $t WHERE ".(count($keys)>1?implode(" AND ",$keys):$keys[0]));
        $st->execute($params);
        $c=$st->rowCount();
        if($c>0){$st=null;return true;}
        $st=null;
        return false;
    }
}

//$user = new user;
//echo $user->verifyemail('boss','2391cc263bdf0fcf6e69872608ee05fdde7dbdc4');
//echo $user->login('1234567','boss');
//echo $user->register('boss','ad min','1234567','waw1@law.bau','1955');
//$db = new db;
//echo $db->dbconstruction();
//print_r(  $db->update(array('username'=>'thoi'),array('username'=>'asd'),'users')  );


class user { // uid | sid | did | username | password | fullname | email | birthday
    public $settings=array(
                'expire_cookie'=>'4m', // cookie expire time
                'expire_account'=>'3M', // inactivity account expire time
                'expire_verification'=>'1d' // unverified email account expire time
            );
    public function register($username,$fullname,$password,$email,$birthday){  // to add : if is expired register it
        if(empty($username)||empty($fullname)||empty($password)||empty($email)||empty($birthday)
            ||!preg_match('/[a-z0-9\-_]{4,31}/i',$username)
            ||!preg_match('/[a-z\s]{5,64}/i',$fullname)
            ||!preg_match('/(.){7,25}/i',$password)
            ||!preg_match('/([\w\-\._]+)@((?:[\w]+\.)+)([a-zA-Z]{2,4})/i',$email)
            ||!preg_match('/(19|20)([0-9]{2})/i',$birthday)
          ){return false;}
        $username=strtolower($username);
        $email=strtolower($email);
        $db=new db;
        if($db->check(array('username'=>$username),'users')===true){return 'registered username!';}
        if($db->check(array('email'=>$email),'users')){return 'registered email!';}
        $shadow = $this->shadow($password);
        $id=$this->gen(md5($username.$fullname.$password.$email.$birthday.$shadow)); // $id['uid']  , $id['sid']  , $id['did']
        $register=$db->send(array('uid'=>$id['uid'],'sid'=>$id['sid'],'did'=>$id['did'],'username'=>$username,'password'=>$shadow,'fullname'=>$fullname,'email'=>$email,'birthday'=>$birthday,'expire'=>time_ahead($this->settings['expire_account'])),'users');
        if($register){
            $expire_verify=time_ahead($this->settings['expire_verification']);
            $db->send(array('uid'=>$id['uid'],'token'=>$id['token'],'expire'=>$expire_verify),'unverified');
            // SEND EMAIL WITH url http://site.com/?u=$uid&t=$token  OR  http://site.com/verify  to input manually token
            return 'Success registration! Time to verify is until '.date('d/M/Y H:i:s',$expire_verify);
        }
        return false;
    }
    public function login($password,$user){
        if(empty($password)||empty($user)){return false;}
        $user=strtolower($user);
        $db=new db;
        $user_check=$db->check(array('username'=>$user),'users');
        $email_check=$db->check(array('email'=>$user),'users');
        if(!$user_check&&!$email_check){return 'Invalid username/email';}
        $user_details=$db->receive(array(($user_check?'username':'email')=>$user),'users')[0];
        if($this->pass_verify($password,$user_details['password'])){  //**********   set some cookies with expire time_ahead('2h')
            $uid=$user_details['uid'];
            if($user_details['expire']<time()){
                if(!$this->remove_user($uid)){return 'int err!';}
                return 'Account has been expired on '.date('d M Y h:i',$user_details['expire']).'! Click HERE to register!';
            }else{
                $db->update(array('expire'=>time_ahead($this->settings['expire_account'])),array('uid'=>$uid),'users');
                $session=$this->gen(md5($uid.'18.1"8-18\'18'))['session'];  //$_SERVER["SSL_SESSION_ID"] if $ssl true
                $expire=time_ahead($this->settings['expire_cookie']);


                /*
                session_set_cookie_params ( $lifetime , $path , $domain , $secure , $httponly  );
                setcookie('auth','sdaasdasa',time()+'120',WWW,DOMAIN,$GLOBALS['ssl'],true);

                define('DOMAIN','example.com',true);
                define('WWW',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],true);
                $ssl=((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])&&$_SERVER['HTTPS']=='on')?true:false);

                session_set_cookie_params ( 20 , WWW , DOMAIN , $GLOBALS['ssl'] , true  );
                session_name('auth');
                session_start();
                */
                //   setcookie('auth',$session,$expire);  <---- (-_-)!


                if($db->send(array('uid'=>$uid,'session'=>$session,'expire'=>$expire),'sessions')){
                    print 'session set!';
                }
            }
            $unverified=$db->check(array('uid'=>$uid),'unverified');//check if is in unverifided db
            if($unverified){
                $expire_verify=$db->receive(array('uid'=>$uid),'unverified')[0]['expire'];
                if($expire_verify<time()){ //expired verification via email!
                    if(!$this->remove_user($uid)){return 'int err!';}
                    return 'Verification has expired! Account has been deleted :(';
                }else{
                    //$rem=($expire_verify-time());
                    return 'success login! Unverified account! Remaining time to verify your account is until '.date('d/M/Y H:i:s',$expire_verify).' !!!';
                }
            }else{
                return 'success login! Verified account :)';
            }
            return false;
        }else{
            return 'invalid password!';
        }
        return false;
    }
    public function verifyemail($user,$token){
        if(empty($token)||empty($user)){return false;}
        $user=strtolower($user);
        $db=new db;
        $user_check=$db->check(array('username'=>$user),'users');
        $email_check=$db->check(array('email'=>$user),'users');
        if($user_check||$email_check){
            $uid=$db->receive(array(($user_check?'username':'email')=>$user),'users')[0]['uid'];
            if(!$db->check(array('uid'=>$uid),'unverified')){return 'Already verified!';}
            if($db->check(array('token'=>$token),'unverified')){
                $db->remove(array('token'=>$token),'unverified');
                return 'Verified successfully.';
            }else{return 'invalid token!';}
        }else{return 'invalid user!';}
        return false;
    }
    public function remove_user($uid){
        if(!empty($uid)){
            $db=new db;
            $db->remove(array('uid'=>$uid),'users');
            $db->remove(array('uid'=>$uid),'unverified');
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public function gen($params){ // generate ids ,  USAGE   gen('user123123123')['did']
        $a = $params.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
        $r = array(
            'sid' => strtolower( sha1(uniqid(md5($a.time()))) ) , // secret id
            'uid' => strtolower( sha1(md5(uniqid($a.time()))) ) , // public id
            'did' => strtolower( sha1(md5(uniqid($a).time())) ) , // download id
            'token' => strtolower( sha1(md5(uniqid($a).(time()*29.06))) ) , // token id for unverified accounts
            'session' => strtolower( sha1(md5(uniqid($a).(time()*19.91))) ) // login session id
        );
        return $r;
    }
    private function shadow($i){ // usage  shadow('mypass')
        $s='';for($n=0;$n<16;$n++){$s.=chr(rand(1,128));}
        $s='$1$'.md5($s).'$';
        return crypt($i,$s);
    }
    private function pass_verify($pass,$hash){ // usage if($this->pass_verify('Zmypass',$s)){echo 'yes';}else{echo 'no';}
        return ((crypt($pass,$hash)==$hash)?true:false);
    }
}

function time_ahead($t,$c=true){
    if(preg_match('/(\d+)([y|M|d|h|m|s])/',$t,$ti)){
        switch($ti[2]){//1year=365.242144days <-maya says so
            case'y':$r=60*60*24*30.43684991666667*12*$ti[1];break;
            case'M':$r=60*60*24*30.43684991666667*$ti[1];break;
            case'd':$r=60*60*24*$ti[1];break;
            case'h':$r=60*60*$ti[1];break;
            case'm':$r=60*$ti[1];break;
            case's':$r=$ti[1];break;
        }
        return ($c?time()+$r:$r);
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can see db structure inside code at dbconstruct func.

My question is should i use for login/logout:

- session and cookie
- mysql with table:sessions[uid|session|expire] and with pcntl_fork for cleaning up expired sessions inside session table called everytime page reloads or something like that!

Im thinking making logins with ajax with refresh

Any other suggestion are welcome too.
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be: use sessions.

A session uses only 1 cookie: `PHPSESSID`. All the session data is stored server-side (so no tampering is possible).

Use [`session_set_save_handler`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) to override where PHP stores it's session data. Have it store it's data in a MySQL table.

Don't have the `uid` as a field in the sessions table. Even unauthenticated guests can have a session. `uid` is part of the session data. Instead of `uid` you'll want `sess_id`, ie. the id of the session. Another reason is that one user could have two sessions, you don't want those to interfere because this can break assumptions you make about how sessions work.

`expire` is fine, use it to implement the garbage collecting callback.

Minor: consider using `utf8_general_ci` instead of `latin1`.